# Reference request about feature maps in ML

Tags: machine-learning, pca, svm, references, kernel-trick

Can someone kindly link to some recent papers on understanding feature maps in ML? It would help to get an idea of what are the recent issues there that people have been working on with regards to feature maps.

---

Here are some of the papers that caught my attention searching for kernel methods in learning,

http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume12/gonen11a/gonen11a.pdf
http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume7/sonnenburg06a/sonnenburg06a.pdf 
http://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~elghaoui/Pubs/LearnKernel_JMLR2004.pdf 
http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume9/ye08b/ye08b.pdf 
http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~saul/papers/nips09_kernel.pdf

https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.02222

http://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wainwrig/Papers/SchWaiYu15.pdf

http://arxiv.org/abs/1501.06195

http://www-cs.stanford.edu/~quocle/LeSarlosSmola_ICML13.pdf

https://arxiv.org/abs/1302.2752

But somehow I feel none of these papers are targeted towards a question like what is the optimal feature map to look for given a downstream application like PCA. (Or is this question not relevant?)